# How to keep this running?

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

So I'm trying to build a bot for discord in java but whenever a command is executed twice,it doesn't work the second time. I know there must be a minuscule mistake or I am doing something wrong. 
For example:
When *!spotify* is entered, the action takes place only when the bot is loaded the first time, and when you again type any *!spotify*, *!minecraft*, *!origin* nothing happens and there are no errors.

```
public class FileEvent extends ListenerAdapter {

public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent event) {



    /*All the paths are here*/
    String SPOTIFY_PATH = "enter path here";
    String MINECRAFT_PATH = "enter path here";
    String ORIGIN_PATH = "enter path here";

    /*All the file objects are here*/
    File Minecraft = new File(MINECRAFT_PATH);
    File Spotify = new File(SPOTIFY_PATH);
    File Origin = new File(ORIGIN_PATH);

    String message = event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!spotify")) {
        Scanner ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new Scanner(Spotify);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data_spotify = ss.nextLine().trim();

        event.getAuthor().openPrivateChannel().flatMap(privateChannel -> privateChannel.sendMessage("sup")).queue();
        ss.close();

        FileDelete.delete(data_spotify.trim(), SPOTIFY_PATH);
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!minecraft")) {
        Scanner sm = null;
        try {
            sm = new Scanner(Minecraft);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data_minecraft = sm.nextLine().trim();


        event.getAuthor().openPrivateChannel().flatMap(privateChannel -> privateChannel.sendMessage("sup")).queue();
        sm.close();

        FileDelete.delete(data_minecraft.trim(), MINECRAFT_PATH);
    }

    if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("!origin")) {
        Scanner sn = null;
        try {
            sn = new Scanner(Origin);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String data_origin = sn.nextLine().trim();


        event.getAuthor().openPrivateChannel().flatMap(privateChannel -> privateChannel.sendMessage("sup")).queue();
        sn.close();

        FileDelete.delete(data_origin.trim(), ORIGIN_PATH);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `try/catch` doesn't loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: When you close a Scanner, it closes the underlying stream.

Comment: Not your bug, but your three files start with capital letters. Java conventions have variables starting with lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to be honest, I don't know where your code goes wrong, but I'm sure you should not chain together lots of commands. The whole command handling could be done much easier with [JDA-Utilities](https://github.com/JDA-Applications/JDA-Utilities).

If you want to create a new command, you should
 1. Create a new java class
 2. Make the newly created class an extension of the Command class like so:

```
   public class ExampleCommand extends Command { /* code here */ }
```

3. Create constructor and set the desired properties for command.
4. Override the execute method:

```
   @Override
   protected void execute(CommandEvent event) { /* code for the command here */ }
```

5. Add the command to your client / jda.

```
   client.addCommands(new ExampleCommand());
```

You can find a complete discord bot example (JDA + JDA Utilities) [here](https://github.com/jagrosh/ExampleBot/) which is easy to read and modify.